# Either MQTT Client is not fully initialized (please wait) or non-JSON message has been sent

Tags: ibm-cloud, mqtt, iot, node-red

When trying to send a command to an IBM IoT node from an Inject node using the Node-RED flow editor, the following error appears: "Either MQTT Client is not fully initialized (please wait) or non-JSON message has been sent".

**Inject Node Configuration**:
Payload: timestamp

**IBM IoT Node Configuration**:
Authentication: Bluemix Serivce
Output Type: Device Command
Device Type: 
Device Id: 
Command Type: test
Format: json
Data: {"testMessage": "testMessage"}
Name: IBM IoT

Answer (score 3):

To get rid of the error, I changed the format from json to JSON (all uppercase)